# Sktilemapnode load tiles from one picture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, tile, sktilemapnode

I have over 1000 tiles that I need to use. In tiled I can use just one picture of all tiles but in Xcode I have to split the tilesheet in 1000 single tiles. Is there a way to make it possible to get the tiles from one picture like in tiled?

Answer (score 1):

If you still need it, I've just done it in a playground:

```
struct SpriteSheet {

let baseTexture: SKTexture
let rows: CGFloat
let columns: CGFloat
var textureSize: (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    return (width: baseTexture.textureRect().width / self.columns,
            height: baseTexture.textureRect().height / self.rows)
}

init(imageNamed texture: String, rows: CGFloat, columns: CGFloat) {
    self.baseTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: texture)
    self.baseTexture.filteringMode = .nearest // best for pixel art
    self.rows = rows
    self.columns = columns
}

var testTileMap: SKTileMapNode {
    let tileSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 16, height: 16)
    let texture = cropTexture(row: 1, column: 10, w: 1, h: 1)
    let tileDef = SKTileDefinition(texture: texture, size: tileSize)
    let tileGroup = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: tileDef)
    let tileSet = SKTileSet(tileGroups: [tileGroup])
    let mapNode = SKTileMapNode(tileSet: tileSet,
                                columns: 4,
                                rows: 4, 
                                tileSize: tileSize,
                                fillWith: tileGroup)
    return mapNode
}

func cropTexture(row: CGFloat, column: CGFloat, w: CGFloat, h: CGFloat) -> SKTexture {
    assert(row < rows && column < columns && row > 0 && column > 0)
    let rect = CGRect(x: textureSize.width * (column - 1),
                      y: textureSize.height * (self.rows - row),
                      width: textureSize.width * w,
                      height: textureSize.height * h)
    return SKTexture(rect: rect, in: baseTexture)
}

}

let spriteSheet = SpriteSheet(imageNamed: "dungeon.png", rows: 24, columns: 20)
let node = spriteSheet.testTileMap
```

This is for a spritesheet of 20x24 tiles of 16x16 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SKTiled](https://github.com/mfessenden/SKTiled) or [JSTilemap](https://github.com/slycrel/JSTileMap) libraries to work with maps created in the Tiled Editor. If you want to use SpriteKits built in `SKTilemapNode` then you need to use individual tiles.

Comment: There is a way. Split programmatically the picture and add the tiles programmatically to the SKTilemapNode, but I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: there are programs on github that are developed in swift to load maps into Xcode made in Tiled